# Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a tridiagonal matrix as below:
$${A_{n \times n}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{a}&{b_1}&{}&{}&{}\\
{c_1}&{a}&{b_2}&{}&{}\\
{}&{c_2}&{\ddots}&{\ddots}&{}\\
{}&{}&{\ddots}&{\ddots}&{b_{n-1}}\\
{}&{}&{}&{c_{n-1}}&{a}
\end{array}} \right]$$
I want to show that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$:
$$|\lambda-a|\leq 2\sqrt{\max\limits_{j}|b_j|\max\limits_{j}|c_j|}$$
I think, [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662225/93400) can help us!

Comment: Hint: Gershgorin's lemma.

Comment: This is not true. Consider $n=3$, $a=0$ and $b_i=c_i=1$ for all $i$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $\pm\sqrt{2}$, but your RHS is $1$.

Comment: please see inserted link above in post.

Comment: @MathMan Why? Your inequality is simply wrong.

Comment: it seems, the inequality must be inverse, post edited.

Comment: The inequality is still wrong. The matrix $A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0}$ has a zero eigenvalue but the lower bound indicates that it should have the magnitude at least $1$.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Is there any similar inequality, maybe?

Comment: In fact, if $a=0$ and $b_i=b$ and $c_i=c$ (such that $bc>0$) for all $i$, the eigenvalues are given by $2\sqrt{bc}\cos\left(\frac{i\pi}{n+1}\right)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. So if $n$ is odd, there's a zero eigenvalue and if $n$ is even, the smallest eigenvalue is given by $2\sqrt{bc}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)$ which can be made arbitrarily close to zero for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: but we assumed, $b_i$'s are not necessarily equal.

Comment: I'm just saying that there is no nontrivial lower bound on the spectrum of such a matrix based entirely on the values of $b$'s and $c$'s; it generally depends on $n$. It does not matter whether or not the coefficients are constant or vary (an inequality valid for variable coefficients should of course be valid for constant ones as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is invoke Gershgorin's theorem. This gives you that

$$|\lambda_i-a|\leq |c_{i-1}|+|b_i|\leq \max_j |c_j|+\max_j
|b_j|,$$

where $c_{i-1},b_i$ are zero outside their specification in $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Post updated. So as **Alex** said, we can use Gershgorin's theorem. we have
$$|\lambda_i-a|\leq |c_{i-1}|+|b_i|\leq \max_j |c_j|+\max_j
|b_j|.$$
I think there is a relation with **Inequality of arithmetic and geometric mean** because:
$$\max_j |c_j|+\max_j|b_j|\geq 2\sqrt{\max_j|b_j|\max_j|c_j|}$$

Comment: There is a relation, but you can't combine those inequalities because they go in the wrong sense. To make an easier example, if you know that $2<3$ and $1<3$ you can't conclude that $2<1$.